# meaning of the word "nail" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/L0BIRPLzohs). It is at 4 minute and 16 second. Here is the context:

> All those things coming because we accruing volume and volume creates overload. But volume will also create overuse. And if you keep relying on this – especially if you are not using spot on, dead on, **nails** perfect form – it will start rear its ugly head a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way down at the bottom of the Cambridge dictionary page:

> **[nail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/nail)** (verb): (informal) to do something successfully:

To *nail* something is an idiomatic expression that means to do it more or less perfectly. The guy in the video is saying that if you are not *nailing* perfect form each time, overuse (lifting too much or too often) will create problems.

Other examples:

> The gymnast fumbled a little in the middle of her routine, but since she **nailed** the landing the judges gave her good scores.
>
> I'm not sure about some of the questions on the exam, but I **nailed** the essay.

(edit) "Nails-perfect" is not typical of the way I've heard *nail* used as a verb, but language evolves and perhaps it's common slang in the speaker's circles.

Comment: I think you're right, but it's probably worth mentioning that "nails perfect" is not a very common way to use this word. In the context quoted by the OP, perhaps it should be hyphenated? _if you are not using spot on, dead on, nails-perfect form..._ And even then, I'd wonder if that's a non-standard way of  saying "nails-it-perfectly." Usually when I see "nails perfect", the _perfect_ is an adjective for the object that follows, such as in a caption like this one: _John Stones nails perfect header off the corner_.

Comment: "we accruing volume", "start rear" - that piece is either not written by a native speaker, or by one careless or ignorant of grammar.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  He's clearly a native speaker, but as we know, language evolves and perhaps "nails perfect" is idiomatic in his circles.

Comment: What about the two examples I gave above?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Without more context I couldn't say.  It's possible that, at least once per day, I shamelessly use expressions that would make an Oxford scholar shudder.  *It be what it be.*

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - You haven't listened to the video. The speaker plainly says, "All those things are coming because we're accruing volume." It's not bad English, it's a bad transcription. (Also, "that will start **to** rear..."). To be fair, though, the speaker talks very fast, and I'd rather have an OP make an effort to transcribe than merely post a video link.